# exponent with a Quaternion relating to eulers equation

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, exponentiation, quaternions

Considering exponentiation of the Quaternion unit vectors

For the first unit vectors we have

$e^{1*Pi}=e^{Pi}$

and

$e^{I*Pi}=-1$

What are the properties of $e^{Jx}$ and $e^{Kx}$?

Any reading materiial on the subject would also be appreciated

Comment: I tried using the matrix form to do exponentiation in wolfram alpha but was unable to fully understand the results alone.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true that $e^{Ix} = -1$ (if the unit quaternions are $I$,$J$,$K$).
See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Exponential.2C_logarithm.2C_and_power).  The subalgebra generated by $I$, $J$ or $K$ is isometrically isomorphic to the complex numbers, with $I$, $J$ or $K$ corresponding to the complex number $i$, so

$$ \eqalign{e^{Ix} &= \cos(x) + I \sin(x)\cr
                e^{Jx} &= \cos(x) + J \sin(x)\cr
e^{Kx} &= \cos(x) + K \sin(x)\cr}$$